# what is the actual use of jquery?

Tags: jquery, web-applications

what is the actual use of jquery ? Just the richness ?

Comment: +1 to offset the -1. This is a legitimate question. Downvote does not mean 'blahh this is simple'

Answer (score 8):

It handles all the differences between ECMAScript implementations in browsers and provides a unified interface to them. Plus the richness.

Comment: It’s not just ECMAScript but also parts of CSS like most of the selectors.

Answer (score 5):

It's simply what Javascript should have been right from the start: consistent, expandable, well organized and cross-browser.

Comment: Gumbo is not saying that kemp is saying that it isn't

Comment: I would like to continue the chain but it would be factually incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

It's a very slick abstraction of common client side javascript tasks with support for all the major browsers. The ajax is very simple to use and it also has some client side UI goodness - easy zebra striping of grid rows, hiding all divs that have a certain css class, fading elements out etc.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is a framework that simplifies the use of javascript, which comes in very handy for for ajax and dom-manipulation

Answer (score 0):

"Write less, do more" motto is really describing what jQuery does briefly.